# Why my object is not present in some of the frames I rendered?

Tags: rendering, objects, scene

I am working on a project and it contains some animation. Issue is that my object is not present in all frames. For example, the object is visible or part of the rendering between frame 50-55 but somehow it's not rendering after frame 55 until frame 60.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the file, https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/49en9yG3/

Comment: Which object is missing during the render?

Comment: Seems to disappear from viewport but it is actually there in the render, the scene is very heavy on geometry ( 0.5 million faces ).  There seems to be an issue with your "Plane" object with the shrinkwrap modfier on it.

Comment: The yellow boat is missing. @stphnl329

Comment: @Moog thanks for the comment. But object is missing in render. :(

Comment: Well...there's only one boat as far as I can see and it's showing up when I try to run the render - ignoring the entire world turning pink due to the world background texture not being present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I trying to render it. It shows for me as well. But in some frames. It won't.